# How to create a custom home page?

Tags: layout, blocks, template, home

I need to create a custom page to the homepage of my ecommerce. In it, I will insert static blocks and html content.

Can anyone tell me what to do to create a PHTML or XML template and call it on the homepage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be default a CMS page (url key *home*) is displayed. It has a WYSIWYG editor you can use and a tab where you can add Layout XML.

Optionally you add a `local.xml` to your template and add the handle `cms_index_index` to add content via layout XML.

The phtml files you might want to include can be put in the template directory with the other template files, you could make a directory `home` or something like that to put them together

Answer (score 1):

Additionally you can call a template file from within your CMS page

```
{{block type="core/template" template="custom/homepage.phtml"}}
```

Where `custom/homepage.phtml` is in `app/design/frontend/[your design package]/[your theme]/template/custom/homepage.phtml`.

From within that template you can call static blocks with

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your_static_block_id')->toHtml() ?>
```